# Populate metadata columns from CSV file

Tags: file-upload, metadata, index

I have a Windows share that contains about 20K files.  I need to upload these into a SharePoint Library (office 365 SharePoint).

I also have a CSV index file that contains the a document ID (which is the filename without the extension - i.e. the ID for a file called 1234.pdf is 1234).  The index also contains some other metadata such as content type (email, invoice, etc).

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to upload these files into the library and to populate the metadata columns using the filename / file id as the key to link them together.

If anyone has come across such a tool or has other ideas as to how to accomplish this challenge I would appreciate it any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Dave